# Javascript doesnt run when navigating through listview , jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing a jquery mobile website and i have some problems running javascript code.

I have a home page , index.html , which is basically a listview to navigate to various html pages. I use the single-page structure for my pages , that means every 1 html file contains 1 page. Now from the home page , i navigate to another page where i am using a [persistent NavBar](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/navbar/footer-persist-a.html) with a horizontal button with 2 options. One is photos and the other is multimedia.

For the photos i am using the Javascript FB API , to download the photos from a FB Page and then with the PhotoSwipe Plugin i present them to the user.

The problem..

If i run the photos.html page , it will work well and load the albums. There are 2 things that my javascript does. 1) Use FB API to get albums, photos , cover photos etc.. 2) Dynamically create a listview with this albums and their photos. In this case both work great!

However when i am in my index.html and i navigate through the listview to the photos.html (photos is the default chosen button from the persisent NavBar) the Javascript code doesnt work. Like is not called at all..

The **index.html** looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/EspacioJoven.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" /> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/custom.css" />
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="a">
    <!--
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Application Title</h1>
    </div>
    -->
    
    <div data-role="content">   
    
        <h2 id="banner">Joven Mobile</h2>
        <div class="main_menu">
            <ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="EcioJven.html"><img src="themes/icons/news.png" alt="Information" class="ui-li-icon">Esen</a></li>
                <li><a href="NeJoven.html"><img src="themes/icons/research.png" alt="Information" class="ui-li-icon">Laen</a></li>
                <li><a href="photos.html"><img src="themes/icons/staff.png" alt="Information" class="ui-li-icon">Multimedia</a></li>
                <li><a href="SajhrJoven.html"><img src="themes/icons/students.png" alt="Information" class="ui-li-icon">Sanen</a></li>
            </ul>   
         </div> 
    </div>
    
    <!--
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
    -->
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The **photos.html** looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/EspacioJoven.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" /> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/custom.css" />
    
    <!-- Needed from PhotoSwipe Plugin -->
    <link href="photoSwipe/jquery-mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="photoSwipe/photoswipe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="photoSwipe/klass.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="photoSwipe/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='photoSwipe/photoSwipeCall.js'></script> 
    <!-- Needed from PhotoSwipe Plugin --> 
    
</head>
<body> 

    <div data-role="page" id="photos" data-theme="a" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">
        
        <div data-role="header" data-id="fixedNav" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Application Title</h1>
            <a href="#" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" title="Go back">Back</a>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="photos.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Photos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div><!-- /header -->
    
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="albums">  
                <!-- Here the albums are created through javascript (createAlbums.js) -->
            </ul>       
            <button type="button" id="loadMoreAlbums">More Albums...</button> 
        </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
   
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    
    <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/createAlbums3.js'></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

As you see i call my javascript in the end. Any ideas why its never called? If i refresh the page , that means run the photos.html , it will load normally.

Actually i also look at the "elements" table from the debugger. When im in the index.html page the html elements seem all correct. When i do the transition though to the photos.html page , by looking at the elements table i see that they dont change! The title does change but the rest stays the same which is incredible?! How on earth can that happen? It looks like is the same page , with the same css and javascript sources , but should be different! As you see i use photoSwipe javascript , css etc! Only if i reload the page the elements are correct. Please any ideas? I have no idea what is happening here.

Also for some reason i get a `304 Status , Not Modified` through the transition , from one page to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is because when you navigate to a page in jQuery Mobile it by defaults will try and pull the JQM page (`data-role="page"` (if there is no data-role='page' then it will pull the `body`)) via ajax and attaches it to the current page's `DOM`, the thing is it will only pull the JQM page (or `body` if there isn't any) and ignore everything (aside from the title) outside of it meaning your JavaScript is not going to get called.

When you refresh the page then a normal HTTP call is made and the entire page is loaded so your code is executed.

In order to have your JavaScript called  you need to either have the relevant script's on your first page or you can have it withing your JQM page wrapper and it will then be pulled along with it.

```
 <div data-role="page" id="photos" data-theme="a"
      data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">
  ....
 <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/createAlbums3.js'></script>
 </div><!-- /page -->
```

Have a look at the [following Q&A](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/scripts-and-styles-not-loading.html) from the official docs for more details.

Comment: My god... Spent more than 4 hours on this and if it wasnt you i would spend another ..day.. on it. I had no idea about that but you are absolutely right. Cant thank you enough Jack! +1

Comment: Your welcome, it will probably pay to skim through the rest of those [Q&A](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/) for some of the other common JQM *gotchas*.

Comment: Thanks Jack, the ajax loading mechanism is worth learning for JQM - I had this exact same problem (with a different plugin) and was descending into madness before I decided to RTFM..